# Mongod not found!

Tags: permissions

I have just installed MongoDB on a Linode server, following their instructions for the installation process. The problem is when trying to run mongod with a control script I'm getting the following error:

> Starting : /opt/bin/mongodb-start: 4: /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod: not found

mongod is definitely at /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod! Why is the control script not finding it?

I've also tried running mongod directly, without a control script and it just gives me the following.

```
-bash: mongod: command not found
```

Comment: You can get working deb packages with no hassle: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Either  /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod hasn't set the executable permission or you are not permitted to execute the binary. Triple check the permissions of the binary.